# Get SPUser from PickerEntity

Tags: 2013

I have an application page with Sharepoint ClientPeoplePicker control on it. 
I need to get the SPUser object for each of the resolved picker entities. 
Using SPWeb.EnsureUser method is out of the question (I've already read many articles about that). 
I actually need to know if the entities are users of the current SPWeb.

Any help how to achieve that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://MySite"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    // Make sure the current user can enumerate permissions.
                    if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions))
                    {
                        // Specify the permission to check.
                        SPBasePermissions permissionToCheck = SPBasePermissions.ManageLists;

                        // Check the permissions of users who are explicitly assigned permissions.
                        SPUserCollection users = `PeoplepickerUsers`;
                        foreach (SPUser user in users)
                        {
                            string login = user.LoginName;
                            if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(login, permissionToCheck))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0} is part of the SPWeb",login);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Stolen and edited from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441848.aspx
You have to edit it with your peoplepicker entities and change the resultoutput but it should work.